# TYPO3 Flux create extendable link list

Tags: fluid, typo3-8.x, flexform

I want to create an extendable list of links with flux. That means I want a backend form to create and add as many links as needed. Using TYPO3 8.7, Flux, Fluidcontent, VHS. How do I do that?

Output Html shall look like this:

```
<h3>Links Headline </h3>
<ul class="mylist">
<li><a href="/one">Linktext one</a></li>
<li><a href="/two">Linktext two</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Seems to be very simple, but I haven´t found a solution for it yet.

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a section in your flux configuration.

```html
<flux:form.section name="settings.linklist" label="Definitions">
  <flux:form.object name="listitem" label="Definition">
     <flux:field.input name="label" label="Label"/>
     <flux:field.input name="link" label="Link">
       <flux:wizard.link/>
     </flux:field.input>
 </flux:form.object>
</flux:form.section>
```

Rendering the list in the frontend with:

```
<f:for each="{settings.linklist}" as="item">
```

For further information see the documentation: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Form/SectionViewHelper.html